# net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, bad URI or cross-site access not allowed while trying to get google fonts by HTML link on Chrome or Firefox

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-font-api

[image: Running Firefox][[image: Runing Chrome[2]]

I getting these two errors on Chrome and on Firefox while trying to use Google fonts.

You can see the Two different errors on Chrome and Firefox:

on Chrome: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

on Firefox: bad URI or cross-site access not allowed

```
//the code:
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
        <style>
            body {
                    background-color: aqua;
                    font-family: Raleway;
                    font-size: 2rem; 
                }
                p{
                   /* background-color: blue; */
                   color: cornsilk;
                   font-size: 2em;
                }
            </style>
        <title>
            test
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please could you add a screenshot of the error?  because [it actually works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/reymon359/fcb759wu/3/)

Comment: @reymon359 I've edited the post with the error screenshot

Comment: Thank you @RaedShihab. I [reproduced the case on my vscode](https://imgur.com/gallery/jde0Qmp) editor and got no errors. Have you tried with another font? and have you tried opening the file directly in the browser without opening it using a server plugin like [Live server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer)  which seems you have done.

Comment: Thank you @reymon359 I tried with another font and without using Live Server and the same problem, but please recheck the post because I've updated it after I tried running HTML file on Firefox instead of Chrome.